# Switching Between Angular Filters On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have written a few different custom filters in my angular module to achieve the sorting that I want, e.g.

**Angular:**

```
var sortByValue = function() {
    return function(input) {
       /*...*/
       return some_boolean;
    }
};

var sortByCount = function() {
    return function(input) {
       /*...*/
       return some_boolean;
    }
};
```

In my **HTML (jade)**, I can call the different filters as such:

```
.row(ng-repeat='item in array | sortByValue')
```

OR

```
.row(ng-repeat='item in array | sortByOrder')
```

**I wish now to add a button that toggles between the two different sorting options.**

---

I tried to do this by defining a new overall filter function that makes use of a `$scope` variable to keep track of the toggle (see below), but it isn't working.

**Angular:**

```
var myController = function($scope) {
    // function called on ng-init
    $scope.initialize = function() {
        $scope.byValue = true;
    }
};

var sortFunction = function() {
    if($scope.byValue) {
        return sortByValue();
    } else {
        return sortByCount();
    }
}
```

I have also tried passing in the `$scope` variable to the filter in the HTML itself, e.g. `sortFunction:byValue` but it also doesn't work.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

---

Demo plunker @  [plnkr.co/edit/altzOow7aIQhqKTN93Oe?p=preview?](http://%20plnkr.co/edit/altzOow7aIQhqKTN93Oe?p=preview?)

Answer (score 1):

Can use one custom filter function and an argument

```
app.filter('mySorter', function(){
    return function(items, sortType){
        // sort logic
        if(!items) return;
        return items.sort(function(a, b){
            if(sortType=== 'order'){
               // order matching
             }else{
               // value matching
             }
        });
    }

});
```

HTML

```
.row(ng-repeat='item in array | mySorter: sortType')

<button ng-click="toggleSort('order')">
```

Then in controller switch around  variable `sortType`

```
$scope.sortType = 'order' // or 'value'

$scope.toggleSort = function(type){
    $scope.sortType = type;
}
```

Comment: You've got crazy rep, @charlietfl. Thanks! Will take a look!

Comment: For some unknown reason I cannot fathom, this isn't working for me either, :(

Comment: Ideally, however, I would prefer to keep my custom filters separate, since some lists will not be using all of the filters.

Comment: Fair enough..can also set a default in filter if that helps

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/altzOow7aIQhqKTN93Oe?p=preview; erm, there is currently something wrong with it! Work in progress :'(

Comment: fix demo so `app` isn't broken and data uses strings not undefined variables

Comment: It is fixed! @charlietfl. Took me some time cause I have to convert ;S

Comment: using [getSortFunction filter](https://plnkr.co/edit/jUhyrWtxj3RVc7xlAWL0?p=preview) and `$filter`

Comment: oh, wow, cool! Thanks! Looks like it is working! Will take a look and try to understand! #noob@angular

Comment: `$filter` gives you access to any angular filters...built in ones or custom ones. So just using it to call one of the other 2 in that approach

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Never knew! @charlietfl. If you would update your answer to include this as a second and alternative solution, I would be more than happy to accept your answer! Thank you so much!